# MBP Retina Isight and FFmpeg

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, osx-mavericks, isight, video4linux

I try to reach the video stream from my brand new MacBook Pro Retina (Mavericks) to use it as an input in ffmpeg (and stream it again via RTMP).

I've tried different solutions in other stack overflow's topics but none seems to work :

`wacaw -L` doesn't list any device

Quicktime Broadcaster doesn't display any video (Audio only)

but the Isight does work in Photo Booth.

Any ideas ? Anyone working on the subject ?

Comment: Is there any equivalent to libvideo4linux with Macos integrated webcam ?